# Putting an image into the clipboard via stdin

Tags: terminal, applescript, graphics, copy-paste

I know I can take image content *from* the clipboard and pipe into `STDOUT` like this:

```
osascript -e "get the clipboard as «class PNGf»" | sed "s/«data PNGf//; s/»//" | xxd -r -p
```

Is there a way to do the opposite? in other words to *put* an image *into* the clipboard via pipes?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of setting the clipboard to an image.  Obviously just edit the image path.

`osascript -e 'set the clipboard to (read (POSIX file "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Mojave Day.jpg") as JPEG picture)'`

---

In **Terminal.app**, you could also create a `function` named `copy`(or whatever you want to name it) with this following line of code.

```
copy(){ osascript -e 'on run{a}' -e 'set the clipboard to posix file a' -e end "$(readlink -f "$1")"; }
```

Then you would have a new command called `copy` which would take an argument which would be passed to the `osascript`.

For example, you could set a `variable` to the result of a command which returns the path of a file you would like to set your clipboard to.  Then you could use that `variable` as the argument to your `copy` command.

This following command sets the new `variable` ***theFile*** to the results of the `find "/Library/Desktop Pictures" -name "Mojave Day*"` command.

```
theFile="$(find "/Library/Desktop Pictures" -name "Mojave Day*")"
```

OK so now you have created your `copy` function. You also now have a `variable` called `theFile`. Now all you need to do to copy the file to your clipboard as an actual file and not just the path of the file as text, is to use your new `copy` command using `theFile` variable as it's argument... like this

`copy "$theFile"`

Or maybe you don't want to pass a `variable` to the `copy` command.  You could just as easily use the full POSIX Path of the file instead as the argument to the `copy` command like this...

`copy "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Mojave Day.jpg"`

So maybe my examples are not true "Pipes" but they are a way of passing information to the `osascript` command.

***SIDENOTE:**  This will only work on single files or folders, not multiple files/folders.*

Comment: That would require writing to a temp file first - it would not work with stdin, would it? (i tried using /dev/stdin and it fails)

Answer (score 0):

Use [pbcopy](https://ss64.com/osx/pbcopy.html)(1).

> Takes the standard input and places it in the specified pasteboard. If
> no pasteboard is specified, the general pasteboard will be used by
> default.
>
> The input is placed in the pasteboard as ASCII data unless it begins
> with the Encapsulated PostScript (EPS) file header or the Rich Text
> Format (RTF) file header, in which case it is placed in the pasteboard
> as one of those data types.

Comment: thanks, but that does not work with images intio stdin AFAIK. Did you try and succeed?

Comment: EPS are images.  It doesn't say it supports other image formats.

Comment: `pbcopy` only supports 4 formats:  general (default), ruler, find, and font.  The only way to get an image would be to encode it (base64) put it in the clipboard as general text, then paste it to something that will unencode it.